# Ternary operator rendering nothing in React when variableis equal to 0

Tags: reactjs, typescript, components, rendering, falsy

I am trying to render a React component on click of another component.

The onClick I set a savedId to be the eventKey of the component to render the correct data related to that specific index the array.

> onClick call

```
 <ListGroup>
                {data.map((item: any, i) => (
                    <ListGroup.Item key={i} action eventKey={i} 
onClick={() => {setSavedId(i); console.log(i)}}>
                        {item.first_name} {item.last_name}
                    </ListGroup.Item>
                ))}
 </ListGroup>
```

The issue here is that when my **savedId** is equal to 0, nothing renders but when it is > 0, the component with the correct data is rendered.

> Ternary

```
  <Tab.Pane eventKey={savedId}>
                                 
{savedId ? <Accordian data={data[savedId]} /> : null}
  </Tab.Pane>
```

My first thought was that since 0 is a "falsy" value, the condition is taking that as false and returning "null" as specified, but I've tried using the **!!** operator and the **&&** operator and no luck...

> !

```
    <Tab.Pane eventKey={savedId}>
                                 
{!!savedId ? <Accordian data={data[savedId]} /> : null}
    </Tab.Pane>
```

> &&

```
{savedId && <Accordian data={data[savedId]} />}
```

> ! AND &&

```
{!!savedId && <Accordian data={data[savedId]} />}
```

> This was my hacky solution and it worked at first but once the page was refreshed the data came back undefined when the savedId was 0

```
{savedId ? <Accordian data={data[savedId]} /> : <Accordian data={data[0]} />}
```

Not really sure how to make this line defensive enough to deal with savedId being equal to 0. Not sure why Typescript is freaking out about it.

Thanks.

Comment: Wait, so are you trying to *default to* `0` if `savedId` is null or 0? What are you trying to do here?

Comment: Not Typescipt, Javascript sees that 0 as falsy. Be more explicit `saveId == null ? null : <Accordian data={data[savedId]} />` will render `null` if `saveId` = `undefined` OR `null`

Comment: @caTS I don’t want it to default to 0, I’m trying to get savedId to match the index of the array of data I am trying to render in the Accordian component, so 0 being the first index of data I want isn’t rendering because it thinks 0 is falsy, but I want 0 included.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of checking for it's *truthiness*, you could check if the `savedId` is a *number* or not.

```
{typeof saveId === 'number' && <Accordion />...}
```

`0` is a *falsy* value, that's why your content does not render, because the condition is not *fulfilled*.

Comment: This was the solution I needed! Thank you.